# Find $P(X\ge 0)$ given distribution of $X$

Tags: probability

A random variable $X$  follows the distribution $$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}
  Cx^2 & -1\le x\le 2,\\
  0 & \text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}$$
and  $Y=X^2$ . Calculate $P(X ≥ 0)$
can some one give me any hint to solve this question.

Comment: What do you need $Y$ for? Why did you define it?

Comment: It is bad etiquette to change the question after it has already been answered

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

- First determine $C$ by using the property that if you integrate $f_X(x)$ from $-1$ to $2$, you should get value $1$.
- Upon knowing $C$, you can now integrat $f_X$ from $0$ to $2$.